# Shade on your Argand diagram the region $\frac{\pi}{4}\,{\le}\,\arg\,z\,\le\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Is this saying the region from $\arg\,z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\arg\,z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in an anticlockwise direction? How would you represent the region from $\arg\,z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\arg\,z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in a clockwise direction?

Edit: Not sure if region is the correct word or not. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Region is OK. Regions do not have directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean in an anti-clockwise direction. $arg \, z$ increases as you go anti-clockwise around the unit circle, and so $\pi/4 \leq arg \, z \leq \pi / 2$ means the region anticlockwise from $\pi/4$ up until $\pi / 2$.

The way you refer to the clockwise direction depends on how you define $arg$. If it varies from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, then you would say:
$$-\pi \leq arg \, z \leq \pi / 4  \quad \wedge \quad \pi/2 \leq arg \, z \leq \pi$$
...where $\wedge$ means the inclusive "or". So that if $arg \, z$ is in one **or** the other of these regions, **or** both, then we shade it in.